# OpenCV VideoCapture fails because Anaconda `source activate` command switch only bin folder but lib. Can I customize this behavior?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am using anaconda and installed opencv into an environment created by `conda create -n cv2env opencv`. After switching to this env by `source activate cv2env`, `cv2.VideoCapture` fails to capture from webcam or read from video file.

I figured out that this is because `source activate` command only takes care of `bin` folder.

If I manually add `cv2env/lib` to the PATH, `cv2.VideoCapture` starts to work. But this should be a perfect job for `source activate` command! But is it possible to customize the way `source activate` command works?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this section "[Saved environment variables](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate)" in the official documentation and amended it so that I can add/remove `lib` folder from the `PATH` with `source activate/deactivate` command.

Basically I need to create my scripts that will be triggered by `source activate/deactivate` command.

```
cd /home/jsmith/anaconda3/envs/cv2env
mkdir -p ./etc/conda/activate.d
mkdir -p ./etc/conda/deactivate.d
touch ./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
touch ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh
```

In env_vars.sh for activate:

```
#!/bin/sh
export OLD_PATH=$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:~/anaconda3/envs/cv2env/lib"
```

And for deactivate:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$OLD_PATH
unset OLD_PATH
```